# Is there a way to print a variable outside .then?

Tags: javascript, database, variables

I want to print `test` outside the .then and .db.get. Is there a way to do it?

```js
db.get("key1").then(value => {
  var test = value;
});
```

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Its not even a "not really", doing anything other than awaiting or thenning leaves you open to a race condition which is never fun to debug.

Comment: @zero298 or leaving you with having to set arbitrary timeouts to wait for the variable to be ready.